# heroku db:push- will it copy my development db and overwrite the production one?

Tags: database, heroku, production

I deployed my app to the heroku servers and pushed the db contents as well. A few days later I made some updates to the development version of the app but no changes to the development database. The production db has changed and its different than the one I have in development.

I want to push my app's changes up to the server, but Im worried that the

```
heroku push master
```

command may overwrite the production db with the development db.

Before I push the changes. I wanted to ask this. Will it override my production db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The push doesn't overwrite the data unless you are reseeding. However, if you have migrations, if you run a db migrate on production, that will change the production db datamodel. However, if you don't run db:migrate, then it shouldn't.

in either case, it shouldn't overwrite your existing data unless your migrations somehow clear tables or drop tables/columns, etc.

Comment: This is correct, pushing code to heroku reloads the code only.  Your database will not be changed.

Comment: Is this true if it lines up with the github account?